# Creating an extension to NSString class

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am creating an extension to NSString class. I have this declared

```
@implementation NSString (Extensions)

+ (NSString *)extractNumbersFromString {

  return [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
           [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
          componentsJoinedByString:@""];

}
```

I have this error: "no known class method for selector componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet"

why? if this selector is part of NSString and I am extending it, I don't understand this error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` is an instance method, not a class method. You are trying to call it within a class method, so there is no instance to which the message should be sent.

So, the message is being sent to what it thinks is a class method called `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`, which doesn't exist - hence the error.

To fix it change the signature of your extension to:

```
- (NSString *)extractNumbersFromString
```